# MYSQL - Не верно сортирует

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

Такая проблема, база данных mysql не верно сортирует запрос, может кто сможет подсказать в чём дело ?
Скрин приложу ниже[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поле `profits` явно имеет строковый тип. `ORDER BY 0 + profits DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

думаю стоит проверить тип поля
Измените тип поля на int и сортировка будет работать

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужна сортировка полей, как текста, ставьте тип поля "TEXT", а если как целое число, то "INT".

Ведь строка со значением "19" будет больше, чем строка со значением "150", потому что сортировка в строковых типах идёт посимвольно.
А если будет указано, что строка имеет целочисленный тип, то сортировочный алгоритм будет сравнивать значение строки целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет возможности (или не хочется) менять тип поля profits с текстового на цифровой, сортировка ORDER BY CAST(profits as UNSIGNED) решит ваш вопрос.